# TextInputLayout - set floating text color dynamically

Tags: java, android, textinputlayout

I want to change colour of a floating label for `TextInputLayout` control programmatically.

I searched and only found a solution using the method `setHintTextAppearance`. This method accepts only a style parameter, which means that I have to define style in xml and use it at runtime.

This is not what I want. I want to be able to set any colour at runtime, based on server response.

Is there any other solution, like overriding classes, or using other methods?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintTextAppearance(int)

Comment: I said that this method doesn't help me...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation to customize your `TextInputLayout`. I have modified one of Stackoverflow's answers according to your requirements:

```
final TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayout);
til.getEditText().setTypeface(tf);
try {
    final Field cthf = til.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
    cthf.setAccessible(true);
    final Object cth = cthf.get(til);
    final Field tpf = cth.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
    tpf.setAccessible(true);
    ((TextPaint) tpf.get(cth)).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hint_color));
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
```

Comment: Where is tf defined and is it necessary for implementation? I implemented your suggestion without line til.getEditText().setTypeface(tf); and it is not working...